# Setting PDO connection timeout time less than 1 second

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP and a PDO object to connect to mysql.  I have 3 DB servers that my php code can connect to.  If I try to connect to DB server #1 and the connection fails I would like to immediately try to connect to DB server #2.  The lowest I can set the connection timeout time is 1 second with the code below.

`$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "1",PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`

Ideally I'd like to set the timeout time to <50 milliseconds. Or 0ms if possible. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: 0ms - giving it no time to connect? You sure you understand about timeouts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible because the underlying MySQL driver won't allow it:

[**Request #60716**: Ability to set PDO connection timeout in milliseconds](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60716)

Comment: Use HAProxy in between PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to set a timeout using milliseconds. Refer to the [php doucmnetation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.connect-timeout) of `mysql.connect_timeout`:

> mysql.connect_timeout:
>
> Connect timeout in seconds. On Linux this timeout is also used for waiting for the first answer from the server.

Btw, I think what you are about to do sounds a little bit *hacky* to me. If you have professional requirements I would use a load balancer. You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.severalnines.com/resources/clustercontrol-mysql-haproxy-load-balancing-tutorial)

Comment: what if one of those servers is offline?  Php is waiting to connect to mysql for 1 second...delaying every other request on that server

Comment: @FrancisSnipe You are right. I've not respected this in my answer. Will update it.