# Limit query runtime to 2 seconds

Tags: php, sql, limit

How can I limit the runtime of a SQL I call with a php file to 2 seconds

here an example I am using

```
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT epf_application.view_url FROM epf_application INNER JOIN app_uri ON epf_application.application_id=app_uri.application_id WHERE app_uri.uri = '$URL' LIMIT 1";
foreach ($xpdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $output .= $row['view_url'];
}
```

I dont want to limit the whole script runtime only the request on the database

Comment: There should be clear documentation for setting the timeout on a SQL call on php.net

Comment: You can't, at least not easily. What is your use case, what is this query doing? Maybe you can cache it? (Edit: ah, it is possible. [Setting PDO connection timeout time less than 1 second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16016731)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't!** As the query is blocking and you'll only know how long it took when it's done.

***So you need to optimize your Queries if they are too slow.** You do that by analyzing and testing and by using `INDEXES` in the right places and playing with `EXPLAIN`.*

Comment: I only have the a long runtime of the query ~4sec if there is no matching value in the table. The table contains up to 30.000.000 rows. Could it be that the query is runnning multiple times over the whole table? If there is a matching value the query runs much shorter. If this is true, can I avoid this behavior with INDEXES?

Comment: @VolkaRacho Add an `INDEX` on the `url`. Might take a while... I usually store `urls` along with `BINARY hashes` and only search by `hash`. 30.000.000 rows is quite a bit of rows. Also learn how `EXPLAIN` works and try to optimize.

Comment: @VolkaRacho Try to do the query just on the table with the urls. Like `SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE `url`='%s' LIMIT 1;` and see how long that takes without the `JOIN`.

Comment: Solved it by setting proper INDEX . Thanks a lot for the hint

Comment: @VolkaRacho **Just wondering:** *What's the speed now to check if a URL exists in such a large Table, with the proper index?* My biggest table revolves around 5MIL so 30MIL Is land of speculation for me :)

Comment: dont know how to messure it exactly but feels like less than 1 sec

Comment: ah got it: 0.0010 sek

Comment: @VolkaRacho **NICE!** To measure performance you use `$before = microtime(true); /* query comes here */ $after = microtime(true); echo number_format($after - $before, 6);`.